# ¿Cómo hacer un alias en bash que se evalúe al ejecutar?

Tags: bash

Con cierta frecuencia ejecuto este comando:

```
eval $(resize)
```

Para no tener que escribirlo cada vez he añadido esta línea a $HOME/.alias

```
alias r="eval $(resize)"
```

Pero cuando ejecuto `r` me establece a 80 columnas, no a lo que corresponde. Si listo el alias me aparece esto:

```
~> alias | grep "alias r="
alias r='eval COLUMNS=80;
```

Es decir, `$(resize)` se evalua cuando se carga el fichero .alias pero yo quiero que se evalúe cuando ejecuto `r`.

Comment: Por cierto, para ver un alias concreto también puedes escribir `alias r`, no hace falta lo de `alias | grep ...`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Los comandos que se escriben dentro de comillas dobles son ejecutados automáticamente. Por tanto, cuando dices `alias r="eval $(resize)"` este comando se interpreta y `r` pasa a valer la expansión de este.

Para que se ejecute cada vez, simplemente usa comillas simples:

```
alias r='eval $(resize)'
```

---

Veamos un ejemplo con un comando cuyo resultado cambia como `date`. Definimos el alias y lo llamamos tres veces, una por segundo:

Genero alias con comillas simples:

```
$ alias d='eval echo $(date)'
```

Vemos que el resultado cambia cada vez:

```
$ for ((i=1;i<3;i++));
> do
>   d
>   sleep 1
> done
Thu Feb 23 14:38:24 CET 2017    # el segundo ahora es 24
Thu Feb 23 14:38:25 CET 2017    # después 25
Thu Feb 23 14:38:26 CET 2017    # ... 26
```

Con comillas dobles:

```
$ alias d="eval echo $(date)"
```

Vemos que el resultado siempre es el mismo:

```
$ for ((i=1;i<3;i++));
> do
>   d
>   sleep 1
> done
Thu Feb 23 14:36:47 CET 2017  # siempre muestra el segundo 47
Thu Feb 23 14:36:47 CET 2017  # ...
Thu Feb 23 14:36:47 CET 2017  # ...
```

---

Veamos otro caso más simple con las comillas, donde definimos un texto que contiene una variable.

```
$ v=23
```

Con las comillas simples, `$v` no se interpreta:

```
$ d='hola $v'
$ echo "$d"
hola $v
```

Con las comillas dobles, sí:

```
$ d="hola $v"
$ echo "$d"
hola 23
```

Comment: todos los días se aprende algo nuevo :D